# How to smooth scene2d ui default skin?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I am usng uiskin.png, default.fnt, uiskin.atlas to create my game UI, but the images is blurred, How do I make it smooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open **ui_skin.atlas** in your GDX project and change the 3rd line to:

```
filter: Linear,Linear
```

It will apply linear min/mag filters to textures and they should look a little bit better. Main LibGDX skin is 'pixelated' by default. You can search here for some custom skins: https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-skins or implement your own in Photoshop/Illustrator with some youtube tutorials. Tutorials would take a week or two but they would help you in your entire life :)